# C# regular expression format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to only allow the following 3 digit strings to be accepted: 083, 084, 085, 086, 087, 088 or 089

At the moment I'm using:

```
[RegularExpression("^08\\{1}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid 3 digit area code")]
```

but this accepts 081 and 082

I've tried using:

```
[RegularExpression("^08\\[3-9]{1}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid 3 digit area code")]
```

but it's not working for me

Comment: `"\\["` in a non-verbatim string will match single square bracket character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex should be

```
[RegularExpression("^08[3-9]$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid 3 digit area code")]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks